# memory allocation of temporary strings

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a question about strings or specifically about the memory used by a string. I'm using MSVC2010. Consider this piece of code:

```c++
void Test() {
    LPWCSTR String = L"Testing";
    PrintString(String);
}

void PrintString(LPWCSTR String) {
    // print String to console or similar
}
```

Is it safe to create and use a string in this way? Is the memory allocated for the storage of the string freed when the string goes out of scope?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is safe, but actually there are no allocations ;)

The L"Testing" will be kept in read only part of your exe file (as a constant set of characters). LPWCSTR String is just a pointer to it, and it doesn't need to be destroyed/deallocated

Comment: Ahh yes, I understand. I'm think I'm just paranoid over causing memory leaks.

I would like to upvote everyones answers. I understand that LPCWSTR et al are simple macros over a const wchar_t* too, that information would also help other newbies. Thankyou all!!

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that `LPWCSTR` is typo for `LPCWSTR`; a freaky Microsoft name for a pointer to a C-style string. It stands for "long pointer to constant wide string", and is an obfuscated way of writing `const wchar_t*`.

> Is it safe to create and use a string in this way?

Like any pointer, it's safe to use as long as it points to a valid array. In this case, it points to a string literal, which is an array with a lifetime as long as the program. So this usage is safe.

If it were to point to an array that might be destroyed while the pointer were still in use, then it would not be safe.

> Is the memory allocated for the storage of the string freed when the string goes out of scope?

No; the pointer will not manage memory for you. If you need to do that, use `std::wstring`.

Comment: Hi,
Yes the LPWCSTR was a typo and should have been LPCWSTR.
I've also experimented with std::wstring to aid with building strings because of easy concatenation, I then copied the string into a static array that I know is big enough to hold the string before exiting the function ( that built the string ). This is completely safe, yes? If I assign an array using wchar_t Array[80], how would I free the memory when I don't want it anymore? Thankyou!

Comment: Oops. Silly question. Static arrays are just that - static.
If I want to use dynamic arrays then I would use wchar_t myArray[], then use myArray = new wchar_t[amount] to allocate and delete[] myArray to release.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to use a string that way. "Testing" will be stored in the data segment of your binary and String will be initialized to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

`L"Testing"` is a wide string literal and has static storage duration which means it's lifetime is the lifetime of the program, you do not have to worry about deallocating it. The [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) in section `2.14.5` *String literals* paragraph *11* says (*emphasis mine*):

> A string literal that **begins with L, such as L"asdf", is a wide
>   string literal**. A wide string literal has type “array of n const
>   wchar_t”, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it has
>   **static storage duration** and is initialized with the given characters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's safe.

The object is a string literal. It means that it has the lifetime of the program.